# How to Print in format specified format in python?

Tags: python, format, printf

I have two set,  like
x=[23,45,67,89,56]
another one with numeric value like y=[1,3]
now i want to print the a list according to b position,. so it should print like this
'23' 45 '67' 89 56

```
            x=[23,45,67,89,56]
            y=[1,3]
            p=""
            a=0
            for i in y:
                for v in range(a,len(x)):
                    a+=1
                    if (v+1)==i:
                        n=x[v]
                        p+=" "+"'{}'".format(n)
                        break
                    else:
                        n=x[v]
                        p+=" "+"{}".format(n)
                    
            print('{0: <18}{1}'.format("Numbers:",p)
```

output:
Numbers:           '23' 45 '67'

how can add the next numbers? is there any shorter way to do this?

Comment: `for idx, v in enumerate(x, start=1): if idx in y: ...`…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
x = [23, 45, 67, 89, 56]
y = [1, 3]
p = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    if i+1 in y:
        p.append("'{}'".format(x[i]))
    else:
        p.append(str(x[i]))

p = (' '.join(p))
print('{0: <18}{1}'.format("Numbers:",p))
```

Comment: Would recommend using `for i, n in enumerate(x, 1):` and using `if i in y:` and `n` instead of `x[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

The core logic lies in the enumerate function. Here's an explanation of how it works:

***for i, num in enumerate(x, 1)***: The enumerate function iterates over the elements of the `x` list returns pairs of `(index, element)` for each `element`(num) in the given iterable (`x` in this case). The `1` as the second argument to enumerate sets the starting `index` to `1` instead of the default `0`. So, during each iteration, `i` will represent the index of the current element in x, and num will represent the value of the current element.

```
x = [23, 45, 67, 89, 56]
y = [1, 3]

p = ""
for i, num in enumerate(x, 1):
    if i in y:
        p += f"'{num}' "
    else:
        p += f"{num} "

print(f"Numbers: {p}")
```